# OpenCSV writing unescaped escape char

Tags: java, opencsv

I am using OpenCSV 2.3 to read and write files data, but when, I switch Windows PC into in Japanese Language then, I notice that OpenCSV write file method internally uses Print writer that is converting yen char to \ 
As a result - the CSV file created ends up with unescaped \, and reading such file using CSVReader fails.

How could I fix this problem ?

Comment: which writer are you using?

Comment: IMO, its would be +au.com.bytecode.opencsv.CSVWriter+??

Comment: I was using FileWriter @PabloGallegoFalcón

Answer (score 1):

Further investigated more on this problem and noticed that, this is not a problem of CSVWrite file method. Although, CSVWrite file methods is working Fine.

Now, Where is problem?

Previously, I was using FileWriter, It uses the system default Encoding. (In other words, If we uses the FileWriter then encoding of writing/reading files is depends on the mercy of Writer).

So, I tried/use

```
csvReader = new CSVReader(new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(inputFile), "UTF-8")));
```

to tell the Reader and Writer just read and write file in specified Encoding system not on systems's default.